# Magento attribute sort order direction

Tags: magento, sorting, attributes

I would like to change the default sort order direction for only one of my attributes. I know how to change the default direction for a specific category or for all categories (se below example) etc, **but how do I do it for only one attribute?**

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: It's for the product listing. When I choose to sort by the specific attribute I would like to change from "desc" to "asc" by default.

Would appreciate a lot if someone could help me out. :)

Comment: I wouldn't think this is possible without a good amount of customization/theming.  The sort and the direction are separate elements (dropdown and an arrow).  In that design, it wouldn't make sense to switch the direction when choosing a different attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, you could update `catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` to use (untested)

```
<?php
    $_sortableAttributes = array(
        'Price (Low to High)' => array(
            'attr' => 'price',
            'dir'  => 'asc'
        ),
        'Price (High to Low)' => array(
            'attr' => 'price',
            'dir'  => 'asc'
        ),
        'Newest' => array(
            'attr' => 'entity_id',
            'dir'  => 'desc'
        )
    );
?>
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
    <?php foreach ($_sortableAttributes as $_label => $_sort): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_sort['attr'], $_sort['dir']) ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_sort['attr']) && $this->getCurrentDirection() == $_sort['dir']): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_label);?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

You'll notice that when selecting "Newest" the direction is forced to `desc`.

This is a *bad idea* because it doesn't take into account the attribute's sortable settings or the sort options in System Config.